# select max sequence number in query

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that looks something like this, where I have user messages store, along with their status (read ('R') or unread ('U')). They are also stored with a status number, to show their sequence in a thread of messages.

```
messageid  userid   sequence    status
93         250        1          A
93         250        2          U
93         250        3          U
94         250        1          A
95         250        1          U
```

I would like to count the unread messages in this table for userid# 250. The resulting rows should be:

```
messageid  userid   sequence    status
93         250        3          U
95         250        1          U
```

I have the easy part down, but believe I need to inner join with a SELECT(max). Here's the easy part, which works well:

```
SELECT messageid FROM message_recips WHERE message_recips.userid=250 AND message_recips.status='N'
```

Heres what cannot figure out the syntax in adding:

```
AND message_recips.sequence=(SELECT MAX(message_recips.sequence))
```

Sincere thanks for any help, it is greatly appreciated! mySQLi or mySQL work fine, as I am in the process of switching over.

Comment: do you want to count the messages or display the last one? Because the sequence number is not reliable if a message can be deleted.

Comment: count the messages, with the status of "N". Messages can be turned to status "D" for deleted, but only entire threads, not individual messages, so it wouldn't calculate the highest sequence number to be a deleted message.

Comment: so how is `sequence=3` representing the number of unread messages for user 250? According to your data the number of unread messages is 2: the 93 and 95, because they both have an unread part in their sequence.

Comment: sorry if it is confusing... That row does not represent the number of unread messages, That is just one of the rows I want to be returned from the query. I would like to count the number of rows returned from the query.

Comment: So the answer you accepted does not answer the question :D But I'm confident sgeddes will know how to fix that. Actually, no. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a given user:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) AS unread_messages
FROM message_recips
WHERE status = 'U'
AND userid = 250;
```

All users report:

```
SELECT userid, COUNT(DISTINCT messageid) AS unread_messages
FROM message_recips
WHERE status = 'U'
GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forgot about DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you wish to get the max sequence number where the status is unread grouped by the messageid and userid.  You can just use the `max` aggregate for this:

```
select messageid, 
       userid,
       max(sequence),
       status
from message_recips
where status = 'U'
group by messageid, userid, status
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69ea7f/1)

Comment: I'm not sure it is equivalent

Comment: So, it works but it's a coincidence. You cannot just group by like that if it's not a requirement. I believe that this won't work as soon as they decide to add a distinctive column and decide to display all rows for that column.

Comment: @Sebas -- can you elaborate, I'm not sure I'm understanding your question?  My understanding of the question is to find the last sequence grouped by message and user where status = U.  This group by is correct for that.

Comment: I will elaborate, I'm in the middle of an implementation, just a few minutes... :p

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I cannot see why this wouldn't work given the current columns? Not adding any columns

Comment: @ambe5960 -- This should be the easiest solution to get both records you posted.  Alternatively, you can join the table back to itself using a subquery, but given your data, this should be quicker.  Please let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @sgeddes, no no, you definitely understand it and this works. Thanks. I will choose this as the right answer, just interested in why sebas has to say.

Comment: @sgeddes actually the original question is completely confusing. I'll wait for OP's answer to my comment